# Chrome won't type Hebrew letters

Tags: google-chrome

I think it was after the last Chrome upgrade, when it stopped allowing me to type in Hebrew letters.

Right now, I can't use Hebrew keyboard anywhere on Chrome (address bar, input fields on website, Whatsapp webapp etc.), while outside of Chrome (Firefox, Slack, any other application) I can.

I tried to change Chrome fonts, and reset its settings, also tried to remove and re-install chrome and tried to use different Chrome profiles, even upgraded my Ubuntu version - but nothing helped.

Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: For those that were following along to this question, some update since this was posted fixed the issue (don't remember which, though).

Answer (score 1):

In the keyboard settings, under "input sources", drag Hebrew to first (on top).

Comment: That is correct, should be the accepted answer. Thanks!